# How to put plotted function from Wolfram Cloud in LaTeX

Tags: plotting, wolfram-cloud, latex

```
{fig1, fig2} = With[{z = x + I*y},
  ParametricPlot[ReIm[#], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5},
    Mesh -> 10, PlotStyle -> LightGreen, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Darker[Green]],
    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.005], Darker[Green]],
    Frame -> False, Axes -> False
  ]
 ] & /@ {z, z^2};

GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2}]
```

I plotted this in Wolfram Cloud. Does someone know how this plot put in LaTeX?

Comment: Export it as SVG `Export["plots.svg", GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2}]]` and then try this: https://www.scivision.dev/include-svg-vector-latex/ . Since this question is about adding plots to $\LaTeX$ it seems like it belongs on [TeX stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @flinty thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is export two PDF files and include them by `pdflatex` or `xelatex`
(you can use `minipage` in LaTeX.)

```
{fig1, fig2} = 
  With[{z = x + I*y}, 
     ParametricPlot[ReIm[#], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, Mesh -> 10, 
      PlotStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Darker[Green]],
       BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.005], Darker[Green]], 
      Frame -> False, Axes -> False]] & /@ {z, z^2};

Export["fig1.pdf", fig1]
Export["fig2.pdf", fig2]
```